# Sorting MySQL Database by Column

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I wish to sort a MySQL database by column. I have a small Database and would like to sort a particular column from low to high; then high to low. It should save the data after it has been sorted.

I would like to do this at the push of a button (hyperlink?) on my website setup that shows the records of the MySQL in a simple html table.

I found some code, (below)

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ORDER BY columnname ASC;.
```

Although am unsure how to actually implement this code. Any help in how do implement this code would be greatly apperciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create index

and

use ORDER BY clause in your query,

```
CREATE INDEX tablename01 ON tablename (columnname);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$sort = $_GET['sort'];

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// SQL query
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY column_name ";

// Attach sort order
switch (strtolower($sort))
{
    case: 'asc':
        $sql .= 'ASC';
        break;
    case: 'desc':
        $sql .= 'DESC';
        break;
    default:
        $sql .= 'ASC';
}


if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
    // Fetch one and one row
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result))
    {
        // Print result
        printf ("%s (%s)\n",$row[0],$row[1]);
    }
    // Free result set
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}

mysqli_close($con);

// Reverse sort order for link
$sort = strtolower($sort) == 'asc' ? 'desc' : 'asc';
?> 

<a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?sort=' . $sort">Change sort</a>
```